# Spring boot test doesn't Autowire all dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-boot-test, oracle-xe

I have a bit of a confusing error in my test scenario.
We want to refactor an Application that is not tested at all. To ensure that we have the same outcame after refactoring I'll write some integration tests for one `Controller` class.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rfq")
public class RfqController {

    @Autowired
    private RfqRepository rfqRepo;

    @Autowired
    private RfqDao rfqDao;
    ...

    @PostMapping("/get")
    public @ResponseBody BuyerRfqView getRFQ(@RequestBody SingleIdBody body) {
        int id = body.getId();
        Optional<Rfq> rfq = rfqRepo.getById(id);
        ...
    }
}
```

In that case I want to test with testcontainers and `spring-boot-test` everything worked well, containers are up and running and the application starts so far. But the problem is that at runtime the spring-boot-test doesn't `Autowire` rfqRepo in the class under test. In the Testclass, every single dependency is in the ComponentScan or EntityScan and the repositories are also injected. I have no clue why this is not working. when the test is running I get a Nullpointer `Exception` by rfqRepo ...
here is the Test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = RfqController.class, webEnvironment =
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ComponentScan({...})
@EnableJpaRepositories({...})
@EntityScan({...})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class RfqControllerTest {

    @Container
    private static OracleContainer database = new OracleContainer(
        "oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g:latest")
        .withExposedPorts(1521, 5500)
        .withPassword("...");
    @InjectMocks
    RfqController rfqController;
    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void databaseProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", database::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", database::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", database::getPassword);
    }
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        ScriptUtils.runInitScript(new JdbcDatabaseDelegate(database, ""), "ddl.sql");
    }
    @Test
    void testGetRFQ() {
        BuyerRfqView result = rfqController.getRFQ(new SingleIdBody(176501));
        Assertions.assertEquals(new BuyerRfqView(), result);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I see EntityScan, ComponentScan etc. I always question if this is correct? Why isn't the SpringBootApplication class in the parent package and everything else below?

Comment: Thats a good question :) ... its an old project and therefore due to history :).

Comment: but unfortunately I have another error when I don't annotated it with injectMocks but with Autowired: ScopeNotActiveException

Comment: This looks like a lot of annotations for a "simple" test. You might want to check Spring Boot Test slices that could make the setup workload a lot smaller and better to understand:

https://stevenschwenke.de/springTestSlices

Answer (score 0):

In the SpringBootTest annotation you are only using RfqController. That's the only class then that is available during test.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = RfqController.class, webEnvironment =SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

So you have to add all classes that are needed for your tests.

Comment: I thought so but unfortunately this is not solving the problem. Its also null at runtime

Comment: And if you remove "classes = RfqController.class"?